# How to use Case Statement with BCP

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I am using BCP as follows,

```
bcp "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[GpsPoint] where id in (551043, 551044, 551045)" -n
```

This works 100%. I have omitted the rest of it because it is just server, user, password settings etc.

If I change the query to this,

```
SELECT id, queueid, CAST((CASE contactNo WHEN 8022 THEN 1234 END) AS INT) as contactNo, recordtime, hardwareid, easting, northing FROM [dbo].[GpsPoint]
```

With a case statement the BCP import gives this,

```
Starting copy...
SQLState = 22008, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Invalid date format
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Unexpected EOF encountered in BCP data-file
```

The contactNo field is an INT NOT NULL in both source and destination, so I cannot see why translating the value using case then casting it to INT is not working?

My BCP import looks like this (minus the server, user, password etc),

```
bcp GpsPoint IN "c:\temp\GPSTracking\gpspoint.dat" -n
```

UPDATE:

If I change the query to this it works,

```
SELECT id, queueid, 8022 as contactNo, recordtime, hardwareid, easting, northing FROM [dbo].[GpsPoint]
```

So it is definitely the case statement. And the issue does not resolve if I use ELSE 0 in the case statement. On my actual query I have a where clause (the where clause on the very first query above) which selects only 3 records as a proof of concept, and they all have 8022 as the value. The ELSE 0 never gets used if I add it and I still get the same error.

Comment: I would also recommend using a view.  You can inspect it, make sure it works before using with `bcp`.

Comment: I could try a view, but it will likely be very slow as I am dealing with a very large number of records, but that is a different story.

Comment: I might just scale it back in complexity and make it select 1234 as ContactNo where contactNo = 8022 and generate a whole bunch of statements like that, each one does a single translation, and union them, or run them separately.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned the `contactNo` is `INT NOT NULL`, in your `CASE` statement currently you are handling only for the value `8022` and not for the remaining values. If you add the `ELSE 0` in the case statement it will solve the issue. It will select `0` for the entries other than `contactNo = 8022`

So the working code will be:

```
SELECT id, queueid, CAST((CASE contactNo WHEN 8022 THEN 1234 ELSE 0 END) AS INT) as contactNo, recordtime, hardwareid, easting, northing 
FROM [dbo].[GpsPoint]
```

**More explanation:**

`CASE contactNo WHEN 8022 THEN 1234 END` this statement will return `1234` for the `contactNo` is `8022` and for the remaining entries it return only `NULL`.
So the `CAST(NULL AS INT)` also returns `NULL` only.
So inserting the `NULL` value into the `NOT NULL` value causing the error.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the problem. I am selecting a subset of data where all the values are 8022 as a proof of concept, only 3 records (look at the very first query above, you can see the where clause I am using to select only 3 records). I tried it just in case, but it didn't help.

Comment: Try adding a where clause to select only records `WHERE contactNo = 8022`